Is this Hardie trim installed wrong? If so, will this cause it to fail or leak around the windows?
Hardie siding was recently installed at my house, and it doesn't look quite right, but I'm very unfamiliar with siding/trim. Will this install cause issues, whether by (a) immediate water issues/leaks or (b) causing the Hardie to prematurely fail?
Essentially, Hardie trim around the windows (and outside corners) was installed on top of Hardie siding planks.
Everything is caulked where the windows meet the trim, but not where the trim meets the siding planks.
Questions:

Is it OK for the trim to overlay the siding in general?
(Looking at nearby houses, it looks like about half are done this way.)
Is the window flashing + trim installed properly?
Do I need to caulk where the Hardie trim overlays the siding around the windows vertically?
Do I need to caulk where the Hardie trim overlays siding horizontally on the bottom or on top? (My understanding is NOT on top/by the flashing.)
Do I need to caulk where the Hardie trim overlays the siding on the outside corners?
Do you see anything else iffy?

Any nuance you have may have re: "this is improper per Hardie installation manual, but fairly common and unlikely to cause issues" vs. "this is improper and definitely will cause issues" would be appreciated.
Thanks for your help and input.





Man I am sorry Ricky.   It looks like a little kid trimmed that window.    Can I just sum this up with...
THE TRIM IS INSTALLED FIRST AND LAP SIDING NEXT TO THE TRIM, NOT UNDER IT!!!
Anything else is not consequential because the entire thing needs to start over.       The only other option would be to have aluminum flashing (something flexible) going around it.
And with the roof line not overhanging that much I would get this fixed ASAP.

What DMoore described is the way my Hardie Plank siding & trim is done.  Trim around the windows & corners first.  Then the siding is butted up against the trim.
